# Terminate SSH call through scripting without any manual intervention in Windows environment

Tags: batch-file, ssh, terminate

What I am trying to achieve here:

I want to automate a daily process of starting a remote SSH session through PuTTY, calling some commands taking its response into a txt file and terminate this SSH session through script.

Now as per suggestion by Mofi, I have this thing working which is like:

```
plink remote_host_name -m "dir\with\Inputcommands.txt" -l username -pw password >> "dir\with\OutputResponse.txt"
```

This actually works okay, but I want it to be able self **terminate** this session once the `OutputResponse` is saved.

Any suggestions on how to terminate this through the same script/without manual intervention in Windows 7 environment?

Comment: The command `exit` results in terminating a telnet/SSH session. So add to your file `Inputcommands.txt` as last line a line with the word `exit` and the SSH session should be terminated automatically.

Comment: this works the prompt ends but however nothing is saved on **OutputResponse.txt** - so I dont get the output in there. May be because we are exiting before the output gets saved on txt file.

I tryed 'exit' in BAT file - but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded `putty.zip` from [Download PuTTY: latest release (0.70)](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) with 64-bit version of **PuTTY** and its additional tools and extracted the ZIP file to temporary directory `C:\Temp\PuTTY`.

Next I double clicked on `C:\Temp\PuTTY\PUTTY.CHM` to open this help file containing complete **PuTTY user manual**.

On displayed contents page I first clicked on list item **2.5 Logging out** and read about how to log out from a session. I read that server's own logout command should be used which might vary between servers and *logout* or *exit* should be tried if not knowing it.

I clicked on button **Back** and clicked on contents page next on **3.8 The PuTTY command line**. On this help page I clicked first on **3.8.1 Starting a session from the command line**. I opened a command prompt window, used `cd /D C:\Temp\PuTTY` to set current directory to directory of **PuTTY** and started to write the command line according to information on this help page.

```
plink -ssh username@hostname
```

I clicked again on button **Back** in help and next on list item **3.8.3.4 -l: specify a login name**. After reading I understood that this is an alternate method to specify user/login name for the host (name or IP address) which I don't need for the command line already typed, but not yet executed. So nothing to change on command line in command prompt window.

I clicked again on button **Back** and next on list item **3.8.3.6 -m: read a remote command or script from a file**. After reading this help page I created in same temporary folder containing the **PuTTY** files a text file with name `GetLists.txt` with the lines:

```
ls -l /
ls -l /lib
history -c ; exit
```

This commands file was saved as ANSI file with DOS/Windows line terminations. I don't know if Unix line endings would be better. Nothing is written about line termination type in help of **PuTTY**.

And I extended the already typed command line in command prompt window to:

```
plink -ssh username@hostname -m GetLists.txt
```

I clicked again on button **Back** in help and next on list item **3.8.3.8 -pw: specify a password**. After reading the two small paragraphs on this help page I extended the command line in the command prompt window once again to:

```
plink -ssh username@hostname -m GetLists.txt -pw password
```

I clicked again on button **Back** in help and looked if something other could be also important, but I did not look so.

So I switched to command prompt window and executed this command. It worked as expected with displaying the two directory lists. (I used PUTTY.EXE months or years ago (I don't remember) for this host and therefore the key data were already stored on my computer for this host.)

I pressed key <kbd>UP</kbd> and extended the command line to:

```
plink -ssh username@hostname -m GetLists.txt -pw password >DirectoryLists.txt
```

I executed this command and it worked without displaying anything on screen.

So I typed next the command:

```
type DirectoryLists.txt
```

And the output was the two directory listings as seen already before.

**Conclusion:** I can't reproduce your problem with my test configuration on the host I connected to.

**By the way:** I used PuTTY months or years ago (I don't remember) to connect to this host with older version 0.64. But it was the first time that I used `plink.exe`. And I did not have any problem with reading in manual and creating the command line step by step as written here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured out that for **Termination** the **exit** part works well but however as I was calling out another remote server in the command it self - i.e. in your case what _**ls**_ does, I was checking for **172.XX.XX.XX XXXX** which was opening a session and I have to automate of giving a **CTRL+C** call to terminate that session and than add **exit** part to completely **TERMINATE**. Thanks a ton.